# Help in understanding this absolute value question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to understand the answer to the following problem.

> Express the following with at least one less pair of absolute value signs:
>   $$|(|a + b| - |a| - |b|)|$$

I know the answer is $|a| + |b| - |a+b|$

But I don't understand why this is this answer.

Please could someone explain how the answer was derived?

Comment: Triangle inequality.

Comment: Since you know the answer, you can try reverse engineering it by using the definition of absolute value: $|u| = u$ if $u \geq 0;$ $|u| = -u$ if $u \leq 0.$

Answer (score 4):

Think about different cases:  if $a \ge 0$ and $b \ge 0$, then $|a| = a$ and $|b| = b$, and $|a+b| = a+b$, so $|a|+|b|-|a+b| = a+b-(a+b) = 0$.  What if $a < 0$ and $b \ge 0$?  What if $a \ge 0$ and $b < 0$?  What if both $a < 0$ and $b < 0$?  In each case, what happens to the expression $|a|+|b|-|a+b|$?

Note to other readers:  Yes, I am aware I am assuming that $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and I am aware of the triangle inequality; however, given the scope of the question and the likely background of the OP, my response is intended to address the question at an appropriate level.

Comment: I have tried this with actual numbers and setting a = -1 and b = 2, then  $|(|-1+2| -|-1| -|2|)| = 2$. I have tried this algebraically and with $a< 0$ and $b > 0$ is it correct to write $|(|a+b| -|a| - |b|)| = |((-a + b) - a -b)| = |-2a| = 2a$? I still can't make the link with how this helps get the solution though. Sorry for not understanding.

Answer (score 2):

The triangle inequality says that $|a|+|b|\ge |a+b|$. Result follows.